# Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0

Tags: php, smarty, tcpdf

My code for tcpdf is

```
$file_to_show_test_details = 'pdf_view_test_details.tpl';
$test_details= $smarty->fetch($file_to_show_test_details);

// Set some content to print
$html = <<<EOD
$test_details
EOD;

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, 'XYZ',$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, ''));
```

The function writeHTML is not working, that's why the error 'Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0' appears in the browser. Could anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: try various examples on tcpdf site, I think you cant do $pdf->writeHtml in header

Comment: @vodich thx for your suggestion, but I want to put some dynamic data in the header which comes from the smarty template. Do you have any solution for my problem?

Comment: I messed arroun with tcpdf a little while ago and disovered you might want to skip calling header and just do writeHtml since you will be able to format it better, At least for me it worked

Comment: @vodich My project's requirement is to put the HTML content which is actually a HTML table into header itself. I couldn't skip calling the HTML data into header. I've to print the HTML table into header itself. Do you have any magic for it?

Comment: you can format html anyway you like, so you can mimic almost any layout

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try to use addPage()?

```
//$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->AddPage();
```

Comment: I know this is an old question and probably solved but I came into this error today and found out that $pdf->AddPage() needs to get called before adding any content to the $pdf (your TCPDF object).

Answer (score 0):

For your case I would recommend skipping call to `$pdf->SetHeaderData` and just format the html the way you need pdf to be displayed and call `$pdf->writeHTML` with correct layout. Mind you that you can also use inline css in your html and you will have to play a while until you get that you want since tcpdf can't render html as good as browser but you will manage to do it eventually. Html tables are your friend here