# I keep getting "TCPDF ERROR: Wrong page number on setPage() function:"

Tags: php, tcpdf

I want to print a class bill and i keep getting:

> TCPDF ERROR: Wrong page number on setPage() function

Below is my code:

```
<?php

ob_start();

require_once '../includes/header.php';
require_once '../tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
require_once '../classes/InstitutionDetail.php';
require_once '../classes/ClassMembership.php';
require_once '../classes/Pupil.php';
require_once '../classes/Admission.php';
require_once '../classes/User.php';
require_once '../classes/Photo.php';
require_once '../classes/Bill.php';
require_once '../classes/Payments.php';

confirm_logged_in();

$institutionDetail = new InstitutionDetail();
$classMembership = new ClassMembership();
$pupil = new Pupil();
$admission = new Admission();
$user = new User();
$photo = new Photo();
$bill = new Bill();
$payment = new Payments();

$getUserDetails = $user->getUserByUsername($_SESSION["username"]);
$splitAccessPages = explode("//", $getUserDetails["access_pages"]);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($splitAccessPages); $i++) {
    if (!in_array("print_class_bills", $splitAccessPages, TRUE)) {
        redirect_to("logout_access.php");
    }
}

//$getAcademicTerm = $academicTerm->getActivatedTerm();
//$get_academic_term = $getAcademicTerm["academic_year"] . "/" . $getAcademicTerm["term"];

if (!isset($_SESSION["chosen_term"], $_SESSION["selected_class_name"])) {
//    redirect_to("student_bill.php");
    $_SESSION["chosen_term"] = "";
    $_SESSION["selected_class_name"] = "";
}

$getInstitutionDetail = $institutionDetail->getInstitutionDetails();
$getSchool_name = $getInstitutionDetail["school_name"];
$getSchoolMotor = $getInstitutionDetail["school_motor"];
$getPostalAddress = $getInstitutionDetail["postal_address"];
$getTelephoneNumbers = $getInstitutionDetail["telephone_1"] . " " . $getInstitutionDetail["telephone_2"] . " " . $getInstitutionDetail["telephone_3"];

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    //Page header
    public function Header() {

    }

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-90);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', '', 8);
        // Page number
//        date_default_timezone_set("Africa/Accra");
//        $this->Cell(0, 10, date("d/m/Y h:i:sa") . " " . 'Page ' . $this->getAliasNumPage() . '/' . $this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

        $takeNote = "<strong><u>FOOTNOTES:</u></strong>";
         $divSaparatefoot = '<div style="width:auto; background-color:mintcream; height:25px;  border-bottom:3px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px;">'.'</div>';

       // $horizontalLine = "<hr style=background:burlywood; height: 5px; />";
        $space = "<p></p>";
        $msg = "1. When <strong>Total Fees</strong> indicate <strong>credit</strong>, it means that, the school owes the student the said amount.";
        $info = "2. All fees must be paid on or before the <strong>re-opening date</strong>.";
        $bankNote = "<strong>Bankers:</strong>";
        $company = "<strong><em>Software by ANIDROL GHANA:+233 26-764-2898 /+233 24-774-5156</em></strong>";

        $institutionDetail = new InstitutionDetail();
        $getInstitutionDetail = $institutionDetail->getInstitutionDetails();
        $getBank_1 = "1. <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_1"] . "</strong> Branch: <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_1_branch"] . "</strong> Account Number: <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_1_account_number"] . "<strong>";
        $getBank_2 = "2. <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_2"] . "</strong> Branch: <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_2_branch"] . "</strong> Account Number: <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_2_account_number"] . "<strong>";
        $getBank_3 = "3. <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_3"] . "</strong> Branch: <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_3_branch"] . "</strong> Account Number: <strong>" . $getInstitutionDetail["bank_3_account_number"] . "<strong>";

        $this->writeHTML($divSaparatefoot, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($takeNote, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($space, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($msg, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($info, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($space, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($bankNote, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($getBank_1, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($getBank_2, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($getBank_3, true, 0, true, 0);
        $this->writeHTML($company, true, 0, true, 0, 'R');
    }

}

$pdf = new MYPDF("", PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . "/lang/eng.php")) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/lang/eng.php");
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 11);

$getClassStudentById = $classMembership->getClassStudentsById($_SESSION["chosen_term"], $_SESSION["selected_class_name"]);
foreach ($getClassStudentById as $value) {
    $pdf->startPageGroup();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->setJPEGQuality(75);

    $getSingleBillAmount = $bill->getSingleBillingAmount($value["pupil_id"]);
    $singleBillAmount = $getSingleBillAmount["billAmount"];

    $getTermFees = $bill->getTermFees($value["pupil_id"], $_SESSION["chosen_term"]);
    $getPTAAll = $bill->getPTAFeesAll($value["pupil_id"]);
//    $termFeesOnly = number_format($getTermFees["termFees"], 2, ".", ",");
    $getPTA = $bill->getPTAFees($value["pupil_id"], $_SESSION["chosen_term"]);
    $termFees = number_format(($getTermFees["termFees"] + $getPTA["ptaFees"]), 2, ".", ",");
    if ($termFees <= 0) {
        if ($termFees == 0) {
            $termFeesFormated = "";
        } else {
            $termFeesFormated = "GH&cent;" . str_replace("-", "", $termFees) . " Credit";
        }
    } else {
        $termFeesFormated = "GH&cent;" . $termFees;
    }

    $getFeesPayable = $bill->getStudentAccount($value["pupil_id"]);
    $getTotalFeesPaid = $bill->getTotalFeesPaid($value["pupil_id"]);
    $getPTAFeesPaid = $bill->getPTAFeesPaid($value["pupil_id"]);
//    $getBalance = number_format((($getFeesPayable["allFeesPayable"] + $singleBillAmount + $getPTAAll["ptaFeesAll"]) - ($getTotalFeesPaid["allFeesPaid"])), 2, ".", ",");
    $getBalance = number_format((($getFeesPayable["allFeesPayable"] + $singleBillAmount + $getPTAAll["ptaFeesAll"]) - ($getTotalFeesPaid["allFeesPaid"] + $getPTAFeesPaid["ptaFeesPaid"] + $termFees)), 2, ".", ",");
    if ($getBalance <= 0) {
        if ($getBalance == 0) {
            $balanceBroughtForward = "-";
        } else {
            $balanceBroughtForward = "GH&cent;" . str_replace("-", "", $getBalance) . " Credit";
        }
    } else {
        $balanceBroughtForward = "GH&cent;" . $getBalance . " Debit";
    }
//    $totalFees = number_format(((($getFeesPayable["allFeesPayable"] - $getTotalFeesPaid["allFeesPaid"]) + $singleBillAmount) + $termFees), 2, ".", ",");
    $totalFees = number_format((($getFeesPayable["allFeesPayable"] + $singleBillAmount + $getPTAAll["ptaFeesAll"] + $termFees) - ($getTotalFeesPaid["allFeesPaid"] + $getPTAFeesPaid["ptaFeesPaid"] + $termFees)), 2, ".", ",");

    if ($totalFees <= 0) {
        if ($totalFees == 0) {
            $balanceCarriedForward = "-";
        } else {
            $balanceCarriedForward = "GH&cent;" . str_replace("-", "", $totalFees) . " Credit";
        }
    } else {
        $balanceCarriedForward = "GH&cent;" . $totalFees;
    }

//    table
    $getStudentPhoto = $photo->getPhotoById($value["pupil_id"]);
    $studentPhoto = "../" . $getStudentPhoto["photo_url"];

    $getLogoID = $photo->getSchoolLogoID();
    $getSchoolLogo = $photo->getSchoolLogo($getLogoID["logo_id"]);
    $schoolLogo = "../" . $getSchoolLogo["photo_url"];

    $heading = "<span>GHANA EDUCATION SERVICE</span>"
            . "<h1>" . $getSchool_name . "</h1>"
            . "<span>" . $getPostalAddress . "</span><br />"
            . "<span>" . $getTelephoneNumbers . "</span>";

    $pdf->Image($studentPhoto, 155, 60, 35, 35, '', '', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
    $pdf->Image($schoolLogo, 5, 7, 34, 37, '', '', '', true, 150, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);

    $tbl_head_heading = '<table cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "5">';
    $tbl_foot_heading = '</table>';
    $tbl_heading = '';

    $tbl_heading .= '
    <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #666; color: #fff;" colspan="4">' . $heading . '</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>';

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_head_heading . $tbl_heading . $tbl_foot_heading, true, false, true, false, '');

    $className ='<div style="width:auto; background-color:grey;">'.'<b>'. '<strong style="color:#fff; font-size:12px">'. htmlentities(strtoupper($_SESSION["chosen_term"] . " " . "Term Student Bill")) . '</strong>'.'</b>'.'</div>';
    $pdf->writeHTML($className, true, 0, true, 0, 'C');
    // $horizontalLineII = '<hr style="">'.'</hr>';

    $divSaparate = '<div style="width:auto; background-color:mintcream; height:25px;  border-bottom:3px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px;">'.'</div>';
    $pdf->writeHTML($divSaparate);

     //$pdf->writeHTML($horizontalLineII);
    $headingSpace = "<div></div>";
    $pdf->writeHTML($headingSpace, true, 0, true, 0);

    //$horizontalLine = "<hr style='background-color:burlywood; height: 5px;'>"."</hr>";

     $divSaparateLine = '<div style="width:auto; background-color:mintcream; height:25px;  border-bottom:3px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px;">'.'</div>';


    $getStudentData = $pupil->getPupilById($value["pupil_id"]);
    $getStudentName = $getStudentData["other_names"] . " " . $getStudentData["family_name"];
    $getStudentID = $getStudentData["pupil_id"];
    $getGender = $getStudentData["sex"];
    $getBoardingStatus = $value["boarding_status"];
    $getClassName = $value["class_name"];



    $tbl_head_title = '<table cellspacing = "10" cellpadding = "0" border = "0">';
    $tbl_foot_title = '</table>';
    $tbl_title = '';

    $tbl_title .= '
    <tbody>
      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%;"><strong>Name:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left;  font-weight:bold;margin:5px; border-bottom:1.5px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px;">' . $getStudentName . '</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%;"><strong>ID Number:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left; border-bottom:1.5px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px; width:100px;">' . $getStudentID . '</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%; "><strong>Gender:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left; border-bottom:1.5px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px; width:100px;">' . $getGender . '</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%;"><strong>Status:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left; border-bottom:1.5px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px; width:100px;">' . $getBoardingStatus . '</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%;"><strong>Class:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left; font-weight:bold; border-bottom:1.5px solid #ddd;padding-bottom:3px; width:100px;">' . $getClassName . '</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%;"><strong>Balance b/f:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left;">' . $balanceBroughtForward . '</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%;"><strong>Term Fees:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left;">' . $termFeesFormated . '</td>
      </tr>

      <tr style="color: #000;">
         <td style="text-align: right; width: 20%;"><strong>Total Fees:</strong></td>
         <td style="text-align: left;">' . $balanceCarriedForward . '</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>';

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_head_title . $tbl_title . $tbl_foot_title, FALSE, false, true, false, '');

    $pdf->writeHTML($divSaparateLine, true, 0, true, 0);

//    list of bill items
    $tbl_head_description = '<table cellspacing = "2" cellpadding = "5" border = "0">';
    $tbl_foot_description = '</table>';
    $tbl_description = '';

    $tbl_description .= '
        <tbody>
          <tr style="color: #000;">
             <td style="width: 8.5%;">&nbsp;</td>
             <td style="width: 67%; text-align: left;">' . "<strong>BILL ITEMS</strong>" . '</td>
             <td style="text-align: right; width: 16%;">' . "<strong>GH&cent;</strong>" . '</td>


          </tr>




        </tbody>';

    $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_head_description . $tbl_description . $tbl_foot_description, FALSE, false, true, false, '');

    $classBillItemsForStudent = $bill->getClassBillForStudent($value["class_name"], $_SESSION["chosen_term"]);

    foreach ($classBillItemsForStudent as $classBillItemStudent) {
        if ($getBoardingStatus === "Day Student") {
            $schoolFees = $classBillItemStudent["day_amount"];
        } else {
            $schoolFees = $classBillItemStudent["boarding_amount"];
        }

        $tbl_head_item = '<table cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "0" border = "0">';
        $tbl_foot_item = '</table>';
        $tbl_item = '';

        $tbl_item .= '
        <tbody>
          <tr style="color: #000;">
             <td style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</td>
             <td style="width: 70%;">' . $classBillItemStudent["bill_item"] . '</td>
             <td style="text-align: right; width: 10%;">' . number_format($schoolFees, 2, ".", ",") . '</td>

          </tr>


        </tbody>';

        $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_head_item . $tbl_item . $tbl_foot_item, FALSE, false, true, false, '');
    }

    if ($getGender === "Male") {
        $classBillItemsForMale = $bill->getClassBillForMale($value["class_name"], $_SESSION["chosen_term"]);
        foreach ($classBillItemsForMale as $classBillItemMale) {
            if ($getBoardingStatus === "Day Student") {
                $schoolFeesMale = $classBillItemMale["day_amount"];
            } else {
                $schoolFeesMale = $classBillItemMale["boarding_amount"];
            }

            $tbl_head_item = '<table cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "0" border = "0">';
            $tbl_foot_item = '</table>';
            $tbl_item = '';

            $tbl_item .= '
        <tbody>
          <tr style="color: #000;">
             <td style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</td>
             <td style="width: 70%;">' . $classBillItemMale["bill_item"] . '</td>
             <td style="text-align: right; width: 10%;">' . number_format($schoolFeesMale, 2, ".", ",") . '</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>';

            $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_head_item . $tbl_item . $tbl_foot_item, FALSE, false, true, false, '');
        }
    } else {
        $classBillItemsForFemale = $bill->getClassBillForFemale($value["class_name"], $_SESSION["chosen_term"]);
        foreach ($classBillItemsForFemale as $classBillItemFemale) {
            if ($getBoardingStatus === "Day Student") {
                $schoolFeesFemale = $classBillItemFemale["day_amount"];
            } else {
                $schoolFeesFemale = $classBillItemFemale["boarding_amount"];
            }

            $tbl_head_item = '<table cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "0" border = "0">';
            $tbl_foot_item = '</table>';
            $tbl_item = '';

            $tbl_item .= '
            <tbody>
              <tr style="color: #000;">
                 <td style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td style="width: 70%;">' . $classBillItemFemale["bill_item"] . '</td>
                 <td style="text-align: right; width: 10%;">' . number_format($schoolFeesFemale, 2, ".", ",") . '</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>';

            $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_head_item . $tbl_item . $tbl_foot_item, FALSE, false, true, false, '');


              //$get_term_from_session = $_SESSION["chosen_term"];
              //$get_session_class =  $_SESSION["selected_class_name"];



//            $get_class_memebership = $classMembership ->getClassMembersByClassName($_SESSION["selected_class_name"]);
//                    
//            if( $get_class_memebership){
//                
//            }

             $getTotalBillForClass = $bill ->getTotalStudentCharges( $_SESSION["selected_class_name"],$_SESSION["chosen_term"]);
             $tbl_head_itema = '<table cellspacing = "1" cellpadding = "0" border = "0">';
            $tbl_foot_itema = '</table>';
            $tbl_itema = '';

            $tbl_itema.= '
            <tbody>
              <tr style="color: #000;">
                 <td style="width: 10%;">&nbsp;</td>
                 <td style="width: 70%;">' . 'TOTAL:' . '</td>
                 <td style="text-align: right; width: 10%;">' . number_format($getTotalBillForClass, 2, ".", ",") . '</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>';


            $pdf->writeHTML($tbl_head_itema . $tbl_itema . $tbl_foot_itema, FALSE, false, true, false, '');
        }
    }
}

$pdf->lastPage();

ob_end_clean();

$pdf->Output();
```

Any time i try to generate a bill i keep getting that error and i dont know where i am wrong too...Can any body please help...

Comment: please isolate it to the exact line where you error occurs, the error message you are getting should tell you the file and line number of the problem.

Comment: as well trim your code down to the minimum amount to reproduce the problem, there's way too much code here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrong page number on setPage() function: 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499685/wrong-page-number-on-setpage-function-0)